# Preferred Email Client For Multi OS Environment

Tags: linux, windows, email, mac-osx

In a mixed OS environment (namely Windows, OSX and Linux), which is your preferred Email client when using imap, but also requiring Calander support? Preferrably, one client for all platforms.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GMail and GCal would be the obvious answer to me.  It also means that I can access it from my mobile devices too.

If I wanted a single native app then Thunderbird and Sunbird across all platforms, however, I don't have a problem in switching clients, so I tend to use the native for each platform, i.e. Outlook in Windows, Mail.app on OSX (I don't use Linux at the moment, so not aware of what is the native mail app on there).  Same goes for calendar.

Although I develop on multiple platforms, I tend to gravitate towards one platform for communications anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Mozilla Thunderbird 3 is a good choice, i use it on both the windows and linux sides of my laptop.

Comment: Do you mean Tbird 2, or is there a beta for 3 out somewhere that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes there is a beta you are not aware of, you might to check that out

Answer (score 1):

[Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) is th best. I use it in my Ubuntu and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've found Entourage on OS X to be a good client for these things, and previously used Evolution on Linux for working with an Exchange server. Both are good. Apple have announced Exchange support for Mail as mentioned elsewhere, but of course we don't yet know how good that is (or not). I've found Notes to be a very disappointing user experience on all OS where it works, on the other hand.

By the way, you don't say what your server setup is. If you don't have one yet, then consider targeting standards support rather than particular vendor solutions, then you'll have more options for the clients you use (as well as an interchangable server architecture, which is often handy).

Answer (score 0):

Novell Evolution is becoming more and more of an viable alternative for Windows and Linux. OS X Mail.app seems to work great in a group environment, especially since it supports CalDAV and will support Exchange out-of-box from Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for thunderbird and lightening but (if you don't mind using Google) add to that the [link text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4631) and then you can sync to multiple computers and you have a web interface for when you're not on your home/work computer.

I use this setup all the time with no problems

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mail (it is built into the browser) treated me very well and it didn't hang when polling seven or so large imap accounts, unlike Thunderbird.

I have since moved to Zimbra for my email needs. It has a very nice web interface, calendaring, instant messaging, iphone/crackberry integration - it ticks a lot of 'enterprise groupware' buzzword boxes.